# What type of quick-connect barrel/pin terminal is this in my furnace control panel?

Tags: electrical, connectors

When repairing my furnace I inadvertently ripped out a quick-connect terminal from the black cylinder (probably a capacitor.) The male end at the end of the capacitor is basically a long, sharp, pin (obscured in the photo by the remnants of the quick connect before I removed it, and the female barrel end (surrounded by heat-shrink tubing) is as shown in the second photo. The female barrel diameter is about 1/16"

What type of connector is this?

[image: Male end/capacitor]

[image: Female barrel end]

Comment: I take it said connector went out to a spark ignition lead?

Comment: probably custom make

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel you take it correctly. Does that help identify the type of connector?

Comment: Brand/model of the furnace? With that, someone could look up the instructions and/or parts list. With the parts list, you could then figure out what the replacement part is and order it...